# Change ip address binding of all web sites in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

i've just migrated a iis6 machine to a iis7 new one with the msdeploy utility.
Now i need to change the ip binding address of all web sites, is there an automated way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through [appcmd.exe](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/). Type: `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD set site "<your site here>" /?`
to see what are your options.

Comment: Yes, i've seen appcmd, but how to make for ALL web sites in a quick way?